# $\alpha = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3 \in V$ then $\dim_\Bbb Q V=4$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $\alpha = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3 \in V$ where $V$ is a field and $V:=\langle 1,\sqrt2, \sqrt3 , \sqrt6 \rangle_\Bbb Q \subset V$.

My textbook says

1. $$\langle 1,\alpha, \alpha^2 , \alpha^3 \rangle_\Bbb Q \subset V$$
2. $$\dim_\Bbb Q\langle 1,\alpha, \alpha^2 , \alpha^3 \rangle = 4$$

Hence $\dim_\Bbb Q V=4$.

To prove 2. is true, it suffices to show that $ 1,\alpha, \alpha^2 , \alpha^3 $ are linearly independent and $\langle 1,\alpha, \alpha^2 , \alpha^3 \rangle_\Bbb Q$ can be mapped bijectively to $V$. I'm having trouble finding such a linear map. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If $V$ is a field and $\alpha \in V$, then by closure under multiplication, it is trivial that $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3 \in V$ and thus that $\langle 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3 \rangle_\mathbb Q \subset V$. However, unless I'm misunderstanding the definitions, it's not necessarily the case that $\dim_\mathbb Q V = 4$, but rather $\dim_\mathbb Q V \ge 4$. Of course it's possible that $V = \mathbb R$ in which case $\dim_\mathbb Q V = \infty$.

Comment: If the dimension were less than 4 then $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3$ would be linearly dependent. Write down what this means and see what you can conclude.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Thanks!. As User8128 mentioned, since $1, \sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt6$ are linearly independent, so the dimension has to be greater or equal to 4. But how is it exactly 4?

Comment: Of course from the information that you just given above it is wrong to say that $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}} V=4$. You can have another field which is bigger than $V$ which is of course still contain $\alpha$. There must be some more informations about $V$ that you didn't write down.

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2):\mathbb{Q}]$

Comment: @user9077 Sorry that I forgot to include the definition of $V$, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what radicals $\sqrt{n}$ you can create using polynomials in $\alpha$.  Two of them are staring you in the face.  Is there another one?